# Is there a limit on how many skillbars can i display?

Tags: reactjs

i've been testing this component ("Skillbar from react-skillbars"), and when i render less than 10 skillbars it works with no issue, but when i add more than 10 using the same estructure in the data, the component renders all skills but don't show neither the bar or the level that's in the array skills.

i've made a loop that generates a skills array based on data passed as a prop.
the skills array has the same format as the one in the docs and when the data makes 8 skills, for instance, the component renders as is supposed to.
when skills array has more than 10 skills, the component renders all skills but no value bar.

anyone else have this problem and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

aparently when you use the component as  for more than 10 skills you have to set a height as a prop to be able to display the skill value/bar, i used <Skillbar skills={skills} heigth={'1.5vh'}/> to solve my problem